# Eclipse XML autocomplete in liquibase files stopped working

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd

Like in title - it worked, for some time and now it only show suggestions based on content existing in file.

Changing xsd from http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd to http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.2.xsd fixes it (but using liquibase in 3.2 version is currently not an option for me, also I can't change file all the time).

I also tried adding something to xsd url - like `?3` on end and it helps. I guess it is some eclipse bug... Anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out someone at work had similar issue - it can be fixed by going to Preferences and then General > Network Connection > Cache and clearing it. (reopening of file might be also required)